# Programmatically switching to a Split View Controller in Swift

Tags: swift, uisplitviewcontroller, xcode6

Here's what I'd like to do: use a SplitViewController but not have it be the first thing that shows up.  I want an initialization view (which does some network stuff and then completes) which then punches over to the split view.

I've got this working. BUT not sure if what I'm doing makes sense and it has a weird behavior.

Here's what I think I know:  to use a SplitViewController, it must be the rootViewController. Also, working with separate storyboards seemed the only way to get it to work. (I've tried having them all in one storyboard but couldn't get it to work).

My first storyboard's controller does it's init and then, to switch to the "SplitViewBoard" storyboard and launch the split view, does the following:

```
let mainStrbd = UIStoryboard(name: "SplitViewBoard", bundle: nil)
let splitController  = mainStrbd.instantiateInitialViewController() as UIViewController

if splitController is UISplitViewController {
    var  mySplitController: UISplitViewController = splitController as UISplitViewController
    mySplitController.delegate  = appDel
    appDel.window?.rootViewController = splitController
} else {
    debugPrint("badness")
}
```

Now, this all works fine.  With one exception.  After setting the rootViewController to the splitController, there's an 8-10 second delay before the split view shows up on the screen!  I'm imagining there's some way of telling the delegate (or whatever) to "refresh" or of just being more explicit but haven't found it yet.  Is this way reasonable?  Or it there a much better way?

Comment: have you tried dispatch_async() ?